# Where to put the equality function for a class in a third party library?

Tags: c#, equality

I'm using a third party library containing a class which lacks both operator==() and Equals(). I'd like to implement one myself, but I'm not sure how to name it and where to put it. I've tried to add both operators as an extension method, but both failed. I've now written an IsEqualTo() function, but it results in rather confusing client code. Does anyone know a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 1):

Would it be an option to inherit from or wrap the third party class?

Comment: Hm, I doubt it would make the client code clearer, as I would always have to remember to wrap the instance before calling the comparison function, just as I now have to remember to call my own IsEqualTo() function instead of the default comparison functions.

Comment: What I meant was: Don't use the third party class in your code. Always use your wrapper.

Comment: Indeed, this would be an option, but it would require to convert instances back and forth when interfacing with the library. Although feasible, it causes a lot of overhead.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to overload the `==` operator, but you could create an `IEqualityComparer<T>` which can be used for dictionaries etc.

While you *can* write an `Equals` extension method, it would never be used because the virtual method on `Object` will always be applicable, and if there's an applicable instance method the compiler doesn't look for extension methods even if there's a more specific one.

You might want to rename your `IsEqualTo` method as `ValueEquals` or something similar... but I agree it's still not ideal.